# Definition of hypergraph homomorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, category-theory, definition, hypergraphs

W.Dörfler and D.A.Waller's paper ["A category-theoretical approach to hypergraphs"](http://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01224952#page-1) gives the following definitions:

1. A *hypergraph* is a triple $H = (V,E,f)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices, $E$ is the set of (hyper)edges and $f \colon E \to \mathcal{P}(V) \smallsetminus \{\emptyset\}$ is the function associating with every edges its edges.
2. A *hypergraph homomorphism*  from $H_1 = (V_1, E_1, f_1)$ to $H_2 = (V_2, E_2, f_2)$ is a pair of functions $h = (h_V \colon V_1 \to V_2, \ h_E \colon E_1 \to E_2)$ such that $h_V(f_1(e)) = f_2(h_E(e))$ for all $e \in E_1$ (by abuse of notation, if $f\colon X \to Y$ and $X' \subseteq X$, then I set $f(X') = \{f(x) \mid x \in X'\}$).

Note that this definition of hypergraphs allows loops (an edge connecting only a vertex with itself) and multiple edges (the same set of vertices can be connected by several edges).

My questions are the following.

1. What happens if we relax the definition of hypergraph homomorphism by requiring only that $h_V(f_1(e)) \subseteq f_2(h_E(e))$ for all $e \in E_1$? Which is the intuitive reason why we do not have a hypergraph homomorphism if  $h_V(f_1(e)) \not\supseteq f_2(h_E(e))$ for some $e \in E_1$? Has the relaxed definition any pathological consequence?
2. The authors say that

   > In the case of hypergraphs which are graphs [that is, the cardinality of $f(e)$ is $1$ or $2$ for all $e \in E$], we note that the above definition
   > reduces to the usual one of graph homomorphism: $h$ sends vertices to vertices and
   > edges to edges, thus preserving adjacency of vertices.

   Does it hold even in the more relaxed definition of hypergraph homomorphism?

I can't visualize any bad or paradoxical consequence of the relaxed definition of hypergraph homomorphism. On the contrary, it seems to me that only with the relaxed definition it holds that the trivial injection of a sub-hypergraph is always a hypergraph morphism (I assume that a hypergraph $H_1 = (V_1, E_1, f_1)$ is a sub-hypergraph of a hypergraph $H_2 = (V_2, E_2, f_2)$ if $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ and $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ and $f_1(e) = f_2(e) \cap V_1$ for all $e \in E_1$).
Moreover, it seems to me that the answer to question 2 is positive.

Comment: Let $H_1$ be a single vertex and a self loop. Contrast morphisms out of it. Do they have something to do with a loopy part of the target?

Comment: @AHusain - Thank you for your comment. I'm afraid I don't get it. Can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: With your relaxed definition of hypergraph homomorphism, a loop can be mapped to a non-loop edge, which is not the case with graph homomorphisms.

Comment: @Bruno - Oh I see, thank you. If I understand well, the point is that in a hypergraph an edge $e$ such that $f(e) = \{a,b\}$ also means that there is a link between $a$ (or $b$) and itself, while this is not the case in a graph. If you post your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @AHusain - Now I see what you mean. If you post your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco "the point is that in a hypergraph an edge  such that ()={,} also means that there is a link between  (or ) and itself": no, it is not what I meant. I meant that If you have a graph $H_1$ with a loop $e_1$ (that is $f_1(e_1)$ is a singleton) and a graph $H_2$ with a non-loop edge $e_2$ (that is $f_2(e_2)$ has cardinality 2), then you can have a hypergraph morphism in the relaxed sense that maps $e_1$ to $e_2$, while a graph morphism cannot map a loop to a non-loop edge.

Comment: @Bruno - Indeed, I agree. What I meant is that morally, $e_2$ can be a non-loop edge because it "implicitly" has a loop in itself, besides connecting two different nodes. Let $n_1$ be the only node of $H_1$, and $n_2$ be the image of $n_1$ in $H_2$ via the hypergraph homomorphism: the hypergraph homomorphism maps $e_1$ to $e_2$ and the nodes linked to $e_1$ (that is, $n_1$ only) to $n_2$, hence $e_2$ contains morally a loop on $n_2$, besides linking $n_2$ to a different node not in the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco One of the reasons I upvoted your question is that it made me realize that the paper you cite and that is mentioned in the references of the nlab entry https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hypergraph does not consider the same category as in this link but this page does not mention it (I think it is weird, it could probably be improved in that respect). Did you check if your category is equivalent to the category HGrph of this page?